# How to set the setTag() method for each listItem in ListView

Tags: java, android, json, xml, listview

I created a MainActivity that holds the list of player names.When I click to that list_item need to  setTag() method for each of the clicked item and that should call the SubActivity.In SubActivity how to implement MediaPlayer and how  to get those Tag.

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     String[] audioTitels;
     ListView listView;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         Resources res = getResources();
         audioTitels = res.getStringArray(R.array.audio_list);

         listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


         AudioAdapter audioAdapter = new AudioAdapter(this,audioTitels);
         listView.setAdapter(audioAdapter);
         listView.setOnItemClickListener(new
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                 switch (i){

                     case  0 :

                         System.out.println("Value of song0 :"+ audioTitels[i]);

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  1:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  2:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  3:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  4:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  5:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  6:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  7:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  8:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  9:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  10:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  11:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  12:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  13:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  14:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  15:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  16:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  17:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  18:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  19:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  20:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  21:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  22:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  23:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  24:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  25:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  26:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  27:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  28:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  29:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  30:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  31:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  32:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  33:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  34:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  35:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  36:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  37:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  38:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  39:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  40:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;

                     case  41:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  42:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  43:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  44:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  45:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  46:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  47:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  48:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  49:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  50:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  51:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  52:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  53:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  54:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  55:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  56:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  57:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  58:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  59:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  60:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  61:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  62:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  63:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  64:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  65:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  66:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  67:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  68:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  69:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  70:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  71:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  72:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  73:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  74:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  75:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  76:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  77:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  78:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  79:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  80:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  81:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  82:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  83:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  84:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  85:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  86:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  87:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  88:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  89:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  90:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  91:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  92:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  93:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  94:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  95:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  96:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  97:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  98:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  99:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  100:
                         System.out.println("Value of song100 :"+ audioTitels[i]);

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  101:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  102:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  103:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  104:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  105:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  106:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  107:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  108:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  109:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  110:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  111:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  112:

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;
                     case  113:
                         System.out.println("Value of song113 :"+ audioTitels[i]);

                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Song to Play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         break;

    }
}
             });  
     }

     class AudioAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

         Context context;
         String[] myTitles;

         AudioAdapter(Context c,String[] titles){


         super(c,R.layout.single_audio,R.id.audioText,titles);


             this.context = c;
             this.myTitles = titles;

         }



         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup 
parent) {

             View row = convertView;
             if(row == null){

                 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                 row = 
layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_audio,parent,false);


             }

             //getting refernce to the textview
             TextView myTitle = (TextView) 
row.findViewById(R.id.audioText);


             myTitle.setText(myTitles[position]);

myTitle.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.list_animation));

             return row;
         }
     }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     tools:context="com.xyz.listviewaudio.MainActivity"
     android:weightSum="1">

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="430dp"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:layout_weight="0.88">

   </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

single_audio.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
         android:textAlignment="gravity"
         android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
         android:id="@+id/audioText"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you explain why do you need 113 `cases` in your switch?

Comment: @pskink I have e url_path like this http://xyzt.com/plugins/quran/001.mp3. I need to set tag like this setTag("001.mp3") up to ("114.mp3") and get those tag and concatenate those tag to the URL  in the Subactivity to play a prayer.

Comment: Just use `setTag(String.format("%03d", i) + ".mp3")`. It'll give you your number as a 3-digit String

Comment: indeed, follow billynomates's advice

Comment: @billynomates, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform click event in getView like this,

```
      @Override
                 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup 
        parent) {

                     View row = convertView;
                     if(row == null){

                         LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                         row = 
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_audio,parent,false);


                     }

                     //getting refernce to the textview
                     TextView myTitle = (TextView) 
        row.findViewById(R.id.audioText);


                     myTitle.setText(myTitles[position]);

        myTitle.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.list_animation));

// ========= Permform Click Event ===================
    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.setTag((position+1)+".mp3");
                    // You can do your code here ....
                }
            });

                     return row;
                 }
```

Comment: ,how to get that Tag in Subactivity?

Comment: @noushadmohammed v.setTag(position); like this , you can set tag easily of each item. In place of position you can set any thing as you want.

Comment: I need to set the tag like this setTag("001.mp3") up to ("114.mp3").

Comment: You can check , yes you can easily set tag like this . Please see edited code of mine. @noushadmohammed. If it helps you then please mark as correct answer.

Comment: How can I get those Tag in subactivity and how to play that particular clicked payer??

Comment: You can just past your tag with intent like Parent Class : 
Intent intent = new Intent(A, B.class); intent.putExtra("your_code", "001.mp3");
Child Class :
String code = getIntent().getStringExtra("code");
By this you can get tag your sub class.

Comment: and how can I play that player need to give all the permission like start, stop, pause and so on.

Comment: You can give where you will start your player . In subactivity you can start player. And your question about tags not how to play mp3. If your tag issue is resolved then please mark as correct and further I will help you to start player.